# How to show 2 lines in 1 with grep,awk and more

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

When I launch a bash command I get this

```
--> '044'    0       ''                               0        
 1> ''                                0         0
```

this is 1 register, i get more registers, how to show every register in 1 line? and if is possible, how to show with only 1 space separating the values?

I want this:

```
'044' 0 '' 0 '' 0 0
```

---

Well i put ALL the command, don't function using this:

```
cdmao;(echo "SELECT nulog FROM POSTE WHERE numan='5512204';"|cuser|grep "\--"|grep -v nulog|cut -    c5-11;)|while read poste_id;do echo "SELECT key_id,genrtou,chiftp, sonsurson, mnemo, order_mla, key_mla FROM KEYBOARD WHERE poste_id='$poste_id';"|cuser| tr -s ' ' | 
while read line; do 
  if [[ $i == 1 ]]; then 
    echo -n "$line"; 
    let i+=1; 
  else 
    echo " $line"; 
    let i-=1; 
  fi; 
done
```

i don't receive nothing: only this >, not finish command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the first few characters are also part of the output, but the solution does not depend on it.

To remove extra spaces, you can use `tr -s`, which will remove repeats of the passed characters. Compare the unchanged with the tr-ed output (third and fourth lines in both cases):

```
lynx@mobilis gemrb 0 $ echo "--> '044'    0       ''                               0        
>  1> ''                                0         0"
--> '044'    0       ''                               0        
 1> ''                                0         0
lynx@mobilis gemrb 0 $ echo "--> '044'    0       ''                               0        
 1> ''                                0         0" | tr -s ' '
--> '044' 0 '' 0 
 1> '' 0 0
```

So the only thing that remains is removing that newline. You could do that with `tr` too (`-d` for delete), but then you would also remove the newline that would separate the string from the next register.

I don't know how stable these register dumps are, so here is a solution that does not involve regular expressions — it just prints the line with the newline included only for every second line:

```
i=1 
echo "--> '044'    0       ''                               0        
 1> ''                                0         0" | tr -s ' ' | 
while read line; do 
  if [[ $i == 1 ]]; then 
    echo -n "$line"; 
    let i+=1; 
  else 
    echo " $line"; 
    let i-=1; 
  fi; 
done
--> '044' 0 '' 0 1> '' 0 0
```

To use it, just replace the `echo 'long register dump'` string with your register dumper program.

EDIT: Ok, if that is your whole command chain, then you have to group them or parts of their output will not be caught by the filter. But I guess `cdmao` is just for some initialisation (if it isn't, add everything in another subshell or curly brackets)?

The main problem is that you didn't complete the while loop (a `done` missing somewhere). Not sure if I placed it correctly, but try this:

```
cdmao;
(echo "SELECT nulog FROM POSTE WHERE numan='5512204';"|cuser|grep "\--"|grep -v nulog|cut -    c5-11;) | 
while read poste_id; do
  echo "SELECT key_id,genrtou,chiftp, sonsurson, mnemo, order_mla, key_mla FROM KEYBOARD WHERE poste_id='$poste_id';"; 
done |cuser| tr -s ' ' | 
while read line; do 
  if [[ $i == 1 ]]; then 
    echo -n "$line"; 
    let i+=1; 
  else 
    echo " $line"; 
    let i-=1; 
  fi; 
done
```

It can be done in a prettier way, but I don't know some of the commands involved, so I kept it close to your version. Anyway, use some formatting and syntax errors will be much easier to spot.

Comment: i pull all the command cause i don't know how to put your command  with mine

Answer (score 0):

This should remove all the extra spaces and newlines in your output:

```
your_command_here | tr '\n' ' ' | sed "s/[ ]*/ /g"
```

If parts of the output from your command is written to stderr in addition to stdout, do:

```
your_command_here 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed "s/[ ]*/ /g"
```

Comment: using this i get this:
 - - >  ' 0 4 4 '  0  ' '  0   1 >  ' '  0  0

Comment: don't function, show the same in 1 linea, but ALL 1 linea, see the answer of lynx, 1 register 2 lines but i receive more than 50 registers, u delete all \n, all registers in 1 line

Comment: Same functionality as `tr '\n' ' ' | sed "s/[ ]*/ /g"` can be simply achieved by `xargs echo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
your command | cut -d '>' -f 2- | paste - - | awk '{$1=$1;print}'
```